# jQuery Slider value undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to learn how to use jQuery sliders.  I can't get a value from the slider on change/slide.  How do I get the value?

```
$(function() {
    $('.slider').slider({
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        step: 1,
        change: function() {
            UpdateVal(this);
        }
    });
});

function UpdateVal(bar) {
    //This returns an object
    var selection = $('.ampSli').slider('value');
    alert(selection);

    //This returns 'undefined'
    alert(bar.value);
}
```

Comment: Are you using `jQuery-ui`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `ui` object in UpdateVal:

```
    change: function (event, ui) {
        UpdateVal(ui);
    }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/723/

Comment: Thanks yo, that was it!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `change` use **slide**

```
 $(function() {
        $('.slider').slider({
            value: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            step: 1,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                UpdateVal(ui);
            }
        });

    function UpdateVal(bar) {

        var selection = $('.ampSli').slider('value');
        alert(selection);

        alert(bar.value);
    }
 });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/724/)